# Changing Highcharts label and sorting x-axis using Django-chartit

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, highcharts

I have a problem using [django-charit](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/) in which it utilizes [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).
So far, here is my code:

```
#creating chart
    ds = DataPool(
        series=
        [{'options': {
            'source': DataForecast.objects.all().order_by('id')},
          'terms': [
              'date_time',
              'wl_observed_m',
              'wl_forecasted_m']}
        ])

    cht = Chart(
        datasource=ds,
        series_options=
        [{'options': {
            'type': 'line',
            'stacking': False},
          'terms': {
              'date_time': [
                  'wl_observed_m',
                  'wl_forecasted_m']
          }}],
        chart_options=
        {'title': {
            'text': 'Forecast for January 19, 2014 2:00 PM'},
         'xAxis': {
             'title': {
                 'text': 'Date & Time'}},
         'yAxis': {
             'title': {
                 'text': 'Water Level, m.'}},
         'credits': {
             'enabled': False}})
```

The output of that is this:
[image]

So, how do I change the label(encircled)? and sort the x-axis. I tried it by the query but no success.

Comment: Where did you set that labels? Change there. Or use [`labelFormatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter) - however I'm not sure if this is supported by Chartit.

Answer (score 3):

SORT :
`DataForecast.objects.all().order_by('id')`
sort query with `.latest()` or `.order_by('-date')` or by the datefield (the one you print to chart) instead of id.